# Find hidden markers in google maps

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So i found one custom map with only zoom buttons in which markers are shown only at 100% zoom. It is not very convenient, so maybe is there some way to show all markers on normal zoom? Some js code which i can add to url or something like that? Оr may be somewhere in the source code are coordinates of markers?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: No, not really, unless you look in the source :)

The answer that is a bit longer:
As I take it you want to write something in the querystring of the webpage, and then see the markers. This would of course be possible if the one who made the site had made code to do that, but I don't think he would.

The only possibility is to look in the source code of the page and see if you can locate some sort of array that holds the markers. If you find one such array you can use a debug tool to execute your own JS where you run through the array and run .setVisible(true) on all the markers.

This is somewhat of a big hack, and I am sure the owner of the site has a good reason to not show the markers unless you are zoomed in, so I wouldn't mess with it unless it was really important. If you want the full list of markers you should ask the owner of the site.

Comment: While debbuging code through httpliveheaders i found an array from google server... It was very long with a lot of numbers, but it is my firs time with google maps and i dont understand any of it... May be you can say something?

google.maps.Load = function(apiLoad) {
    delete google.maps.Load;
    apiLoad([null,[[["http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?l....... and after it comes something like this ,[386930130,1288476560]],[[350277470,1288476560],[38693

Comment: I don't think you need to concern yourself with the thing you posted. The array you are looking for should not be coming from the Google server, but instead be on the source code for the page you are looking at.

Comment: Oh, may be you have some example ot this array?

Comment: No sorry.. The array is something custom that the implementer of the site has made by himself :) It will usually be called markers though.